# Referencing a range of equations with a particular format (A.3-7) instead of (A.3)-(A.7)

Tags: cross-referencing

How can I reference a range of equations in the form I want? For example, I want to reference a range of equations starting with Eq. (A.3) and ending with Eq. (A.7), what is a simple way to get the reference to display as Eq. (A.3-7)? I know how to get (A.3-A.7) but I don't love the way it looks.

ETA working example:

```latex
\begin{align}
a &= b  \label{eq:beg} \\
b &= c  \\
c &= d  \\
d &= e  \\
e &= f  \label{eq:end}
\end{align}

You can see from Eq.~(\ref{eq:beg}-(\ref{eq:end}) that $a = f$
```

This displays

```
You can see from Eq. (A.3-A.7) that a=f
```

but I want it to display

```
You can see from Eq. (A.3-7) that a=f
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you willing and able to use the `cleveref` package to create cross-referencing call-outs?

Comment: @Mico Sure, I made a quick attempt at cleveref but found that it was formatting (A.3) to (A.7), which isn't the output I want. How can I do what I want using cleveref?

Comment: You need to check out p. 20 of the package's user guide. Anyway, I'm about to post an answer that makes use of `cleveref`'s machinery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formatting objective may be achieved in a straightforward manner by employing some of the machinery of the `cleveref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}% see p. 20 of package's user guide
    {(#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6)}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\crefrange{eq:c}{eq:g}, 
\labelcref{eq:c,eq:g,eq:e,eq:d,eq:f} % input arguments needn't be sorted

\appendix
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\section{Supplemental material}
\begin{equation} a \label{eq:a} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} b \label{eq:b} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} c \label{eq:c} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} d \label{eq:d} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} e \label{eq:e} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} f \label{eq:f} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} g \label{eq:g} \end{equation}
\end{document}
```