# Any way to reference a particular component of a label?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I am using `numberwithin` to number my figures within their section. For example, I have figures 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3 in section 1 and figures 2.1 and 2.2 in section 2. What I want to do is reference just the figure number, and not the section. For example, I want a reference to read "figures 1.1-3". Is there any way to do this?

Here is what I believe to be the relevant part of the preamble in my document:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epsfig}  
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}
```

The following is a small example with respect to the above preamble:

```
\begin{document}

\title{Example}
\titlerunning{Example}

\author{Me}

\maketitle

\section{First Section}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{First Figure}
\label{fig:1.1}
This is a figure.
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Second Figure}
\label{fig:1.2}
This is another figure.
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Third Figure}
\label{fig:1.3}
This is yet another figure.
\end{figure}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Fourth Figure}
\label{fig:2.1}
This is a figure in the second section.
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Fifth Figure}
\label{fig:2.2}
This is another figure in the second section.
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
As you can see in figures \ref{fig:1.1}-\ref{fig:1.3}, the numbering is not what I'd like. I want it to read "figures 1.1-3".

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which package(s), if any, you load at present to create cross-references.

Comment: I don't think I am loading any packages for cross-references. Please see my edit including the preamble to my document.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you load the `graphicx` package, there's no need for the `epsfig` package. None.

Comment: Fair enough. It ended up working. I'll accept other answers if they work, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `cleveref` package provides some machinery to "strip" the prefix component from an object's number when creating cross-references to *ranges* of objects, such as `figure` environments.

(In some cases such as Roman numbering, `cleveref`'s `\crefstripprefix` machinery may not be enough, though, and you might need `xstring`'s `\StrCut`.)

For more information on this method, see page 20 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package as well as postings such as [Referencing a range of equations with a particular format (A.3-7) instead of (A.3)-(A.7)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565764/5001), [Crossreference in Ref Range (1a-1e) to (1a-e)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135151/5001), and [Refer to a range of subsubexamples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633875/refer-to-a-range-of-subsubexamples).

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for '\numberwithin' macro
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}  % see https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\begin{document}
%% The following is _minimalist_ code
\setcounter{section}{1}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:aa}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:bb}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:cc}

A cross-reference to \cref{fig:aa,fig:cc,fig:bb}. % arguments of '\cref' needen't be sorted by the user
\end {document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The solution method proposed here lets writers use `\cref` to create multiple cross-referencing call-outs to *ranges* of numbers, with the number prefix being stripped off for each range of numbers. For instance,

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}  % see https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\begin{document}
%% The following is _minimalist_ code; it's not how one would normally
%% go about creating 'figure' environments, captions, and labels.
\setcounter{section}{1}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:aa} % 1.1
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:bb} % 1.2
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:cc} % 1.3
\stepcounter{section}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:dd} % 2.1
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:ee} % 2.2
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:ff} % 2.3
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:gg} % 2.4

%% Now the call to \cref. Note that the arguments of \cref
%% need not be sorted in any order.
A cross-reference to \cref{fig:aa,fig:cc,fig:gg,fig:ee,fig:ff,fig:bb}. 
\end {document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can load the package [refcount](https://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) and define a macro `\RefOnlyStuffBehindLastDot`  which uses refcount's `\getrefbykeydefault` for extracting the number from the reference before applying a tail-recursive macro which from the extracted number removes dot-delimited arguments until no dots are left:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{refcount}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\gobbletodot{\long\def\gobbletodot#1.{}}%
\newcommand\KeepOnlyStuffBehindLastDot[1]{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\gobbletodot#1.}$%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {#1}{\expandafter\KeepOnlyStuffBehindLastDot\expandafter{\gobbletodot#1}}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\RefOnlyStuffBehindLastDot{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\RefOnlyStuffBehindLastDot[1]{%
    \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{\refused{#1}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%
                        {%
                          \@ifundefined{hyperref}{\@firstofone}{\hyperref[{#1}]}%
                          {%
                            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\KeepOnlyStuffBehindLastDot
                            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{??}}%
                          }%
                        }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

% \usepackage{hyperref}

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epsfig}  
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\title{Example}
\titlerunning{Example}

\author{Me}

\maketitle

\section{First Section}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{First Figure}
\label{fig:1.1}
This is a figure.
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Second Figure}
\label{fig:1.2}
This is another figure.
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Third Figure}
\label{fig:1.3}
This is yet another figure.
\end{figure}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Fourth Figure}
\label{fig:2.1}
This is a figure in the second section.
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{Fifth Figure}
\label{fig:2.2}
This is another figure in the second section.
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
As you can see in figures \ref{fig:1.1}-\ref{fig:1.3}, the numbering is not what I'd like. I want it to read "figures 1.1-3".

As you can see in figures \ref{fig:1.1}-\RefOnlyStuffBehindLastDot{fig:1.3}, the numbering what I like. I want it to read "figures 1.1-3".

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But what if there is no dot/delimiter ? Can you use \getrefbykeydefault to call the sublabel ?

Comment: @VincentKrebs The macro `\RefOnlyStuffBehindLastDot` iteratively removes dot-delimited arguments until there is no more dot. If in the beginning there is no dot, nothing  gets removed. What do you mean when using the phrase "sublabel"?

Comment: Makes sense. But I was talking about `\getrefbykeydefault` precisely.
Was a shortcut for "sublevel label" (call it "alone", skipping the main level label).

Comment: @VincentKrebs  You can use `\getrefbykeydefault` with any cross-referencing-label for obtaining the tokens that form the textual phrase of the cross-reference. This is useful when the package hyperref is loaded where commands like `\ref`/`\pageref` do not just deliver tokens for textual phrases but wrap tokens for textual phrases between additional tokens for turning things into hyperlinks.

Comment: Wonderful, I played with it somehow and that's what I thought, I'll have to find some documentation. I think what I am talking about here is a wrong problem, i.e. I do not need a delimiter to skip tokens https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643863/262813

Comment: I would like to do what @frabjous is suggesting in the comments of the post I've just linked above, but I'm not sure.
Then I could forget this crazy post I wrote https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637115/262813

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using any fancy cross-referencing packages, you can just set the reference to whatever you like before setting a `\label` by changing `\@currentlabel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

See Figures \ref{fig:first}--\ref{fig:final}, 
or Figures~\ref{fig:first}--\ref{fig:final-final}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{First figure}\label{fig:first}% 1.1
  \caption{Second figure}\label{fig:second}% 1.2
  \caption{Third figure}\label{fig:third}% 1.3
  \caption{Final figure}\label{fig:final}% 1.4
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{\arabic{figure}}\label{fig:final-final}% 4
  \makeatother
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```