# How to adapt \crefrangelabelformat to subexample formatting?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, preamble, definition, linguex

I would like to be able to redefine something which is supposed to be defined in the preamble.

In this example and in relation to this question :
[Cross-referencing: more sublevels, and presets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637164/262813),
I want to redefine \crefrangelabelformat of the `cleveref` package, but it doesn't work, see the MWE and its output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{philex}


%MyStripToColon (requires xstring)
\newcommand{\mystriptocolon}[2]{\StrCut{#1}{.}{\myonea}{\myoneb}%
    \StrCut{#2}{.}{\mytwoa}{\mytwob}%
    \IfStrEq{\myonea}{\mytwoa}{\mytwob}{#2}}



    % Cleveref Label Formatting

            \crefname{ExNo}{}{}
            \crefname{SubExNo}{}{}
            \crefname{SubSubExNo}{}{}
        
            \creflabelformat{ExNo}{#2#1#3}          % The output of the \cref command doesn't include parentheses.
            \creflabelformat{SubExNo}{#2#1#3}
            \creflabelformat{SubSubExNo}{#2#1#3}        
            
            \crefrangelabelformat{ExNo}{#3#1#4--#5#2#6}                 
            \crefrangelabelformat{SubExNo}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}        
            \crefrangelabelformat{SubSubExNo}{#3#1#4--#5\mystriptocolon{#1}{#2}#6}
            
            \newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{–} 

\begin{document}


    % Philex Label Formatting
    
            \phildashes{}{.}        
            \subformat{a}{}{.}
            \subsubformat{i}{(}{)}

        \lb{main1}{This is main1.
            \lba{sub1}{This is sub1.
                \lba{subsub11}{This is subsub11.}
                \lbz{subsub12}{This is subsub12.}}
            \lbz{sub2}{This is sub2.
                \lba{subsub21}{This is subsub21.}
                \lbz{subsub22}{This is subsub22.}}}
                
        \lb{main2}{This is main2.}
                


\textbackslash mystriptocolon works like a charm:

\vspace{6pt}

\textbackslash crefrange\{sub1\}\{sub2\} \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{sub1}{sub2}

\vspace{6pt}

\textbackslash crefrange\{subsub11\}\{subsub12\} \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{subsub11}{subsub12}

\vspace{6pt}


\textbf{Now I change label formatting.}
    
            \phildashes{.}{}    
            \subformat{1}{}{.}  
            \subsubformat{a}{}{.}   
    
\lb{main3}{This is main3.
    \lba{sub31}{This is sub31.
        \lba{subsub311}{This is subsub311.}
        \lbz{subsub312}{This is subsub312.}}
    \lbz{sub32}{This is sub32.}}
    
\vspace{6pt}
            
\textbf{Trying to redefine \textbackslash crefrangelabelformat in order for the new subsublevel format to be supported, now that there is no separator:}

\vspace{6pt}
        
\textbackslash crefrangelabelformat\{SubSubExNo\}\{\#3\#1\#4--\#5\textbackslash crefstripprefix\{\#1\}\{\#2\}\#6\}

\crefrangelabelformat{SubSubExNo}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\textbackslash crefrange\{subsub311\}\{subsub312\} \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{subsub311}{subsub312}

\vspace{6pt}

As you can see, the new \textbackslash crefrangelabelformat has not been taken into account and I cannot use \textbackslash crefstripprefix, I would like to obtain 3.1a--b but the 1 is repeated.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well I have neither the time nor the will to wade into cleveref and this philex package, but generally: When I want to setup some sophisticated references I avoid cleveref and define the commands myself with zref. There you have more control over the data structure, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325319/2388

Comment: Now I do use `zref`. If anyone wants to quickly see how this jewel works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644002/262813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remarks:

1. The hyperref-support of the package philex is very messy:

   - It is not ensured at all that each named desination/target/anchor for hyperlinks has a unique name.
     As a consequence you get a lot of warnings like `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{altsub.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored` when using TeX-engines based on pdfTeX. As another consequence with all TeX-engines **it is not ensured at all that hyperlinks lead to correct places in the pdf-document**.
     One reason for this is: There may take place a lot of resetting of counters. With hyperref names of many destinations/targets/anchors are created automatically when `\refstepcounter` is carried out. These destination-names are derived from the names and the values of the counters incremented. Thus if the value of a counter is reset, uniqueness of names of destinations/targets/anchors is not ensured any more. This could probably be fixed: When hyperref is loaded, then each counter, besides the well-known `\the⟨counter⟩`-macro, also has an associated `\theH⟨counter⟩`-macro denoting how `\refstepcounter` shall create names of destinations/targets/anchors when the counter in question is incremented. Seems the package maintainer of philex did not take maintenance of `\theH⟨counter⟩`-macros into account.
   - On CTAN you get a .sty-file where line-breaking looks weird and where in some places you find many unnecessary `%` and where in other places `%` seem to be missing. I won't delve into the code of that package. But I recommend not using it until it is fixed.
2. You say:

   *"I would like to be able to redefine something which is supposed to be defined in the preamble."*

   How about not redefining but about already within the preamble defining things so that their behavior depends, e.g., on the value of a counter-flag?
   If you do this, you can select behavior by redefining to another value the macro that denotes the counter-flag.

   With the example below a macro for selecting one of several brace-nested macro-arguments is provided:

   ```
   \ExtractKthArg{⟨TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity of value K⟩}%
                 {⟨tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argument⟩}%
                 {⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩}
   ```

   In case there is no K-th argument in *⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩*:
         Does deliver *⟨tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K-th argument⟩*.
   In case there is a K-th argument in *⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩*:
         Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.

   With the example below a macro `\StyleFlag` is defined. Expanding `\StyleFlag` should always yield a valid TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity.

   With the example below a macro `\SetStyleFlag{⟨TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity⟩}` is defined so that you can easily assign another value to `\StyleFlag`.

   With the example below a macro `\SelectAccordingToStyleFlag` is provided. Internally it uses `\ExtractKthArg` with `\StyleFlag` as its *⟨TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity of value K⟩*-argument. Syntax of `\SelectAccordingToStyleFlag` is:

   ```
   \SelectAccordingToStyleFlag{⟨Default-Tokens⟩}{%
      {⟨Tokens if value of \StyleFlag is 1⟩}%
      {⟨Tokens if value of \StyleFlag is 2⟩}%
      {⟨Tokens if value of \StyleFlag is 3⟩}%
      ...%
   }%
   ```

   *⟨Default-Tokens⟩* is used if `\StyleFlag` denotes a value K so that the following list does not have a K-th argument.

   You can use `\SelectAccordingToStyleFlag`, e.g., when setting some `\crefrangelabelformat` within the preamble.

   Within the document-environment you can change the behavior of corresponding `\crefrange`s by setting the style-flag to another value via `\SetStyleFlag`.

The example below just exhibits one way of coping with the problem that cleveref's `\cref...name`- and `\cref...format`-macros cannot be redefined within the document-environment.

**The example below does not cope with the deficiencies of the philex package regarding proper hyperref-support.**

```latex
\makeatletter
%% Code for \ExtractKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<TeX-<number>-quantity of value K>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent>}%
%%               {<list of undelimited args>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <action if there is no K-th argument>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{% empty
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\begingroup
\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax##1##2#1{{##1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo##3{}.}{\UD@stopromannumeral##2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##1}{%
        \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{##3#1}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##3}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}{##2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%% Usage of frozen-\relax as delimiter is for speeding things up by reducing the
%% amount of iterations needed. I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle 
%% pointed out in   <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
\makeatother


%==============================================================================
% \SelectAccordingToStyleFlag
%==============================================================================
%
% Syntax:
%
% \SetStyleFlag{1} or \SetStyleFlag{2} or \SetStyleFlag{3} or ....
%
% \SelectAccordingToStyleFlag{<Default-Tokens>}{%
%   {<Tokens if value of \StyleFlag is 1>}%
%   {<Tokens if value of \StyleFlag is 2>}%
%   {<Tokens if value of \StyleFlag is 3>}%
%   ...%
% }%
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\StyleFlag{1}%
\newcommand\SetStyleFlag[1]{\@bsphack\def\StyleFlag{#1}\@esphack}%
\newcommand\SelectAccordingToStyleFlag{%
  \ExtractKthArg{\StyleFlag}%
}%
\makeatother
%==============================================================================


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[hyper]{philex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xstring}

%% Enable the following lines to see the coming into being of duplicate
%% destination/target/anchor-names more explicitly in the console-output - the
%% problem about warnings of pattern
%%    pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{altsubsub.1}) 
%%    has been already used, duplicate ignored
%% still needs to be fixed by fixing what the macros coming from the philex-package
%% do. Probably by taking \theH<counter>-macros associated to philex's counters
%% into account:
%\makeatletter
%\AtBeginDocument{%
%  \let\oldhypertarget\hypertarget
%  \def\hypertarget#1{\message{^^J!!!Target-Name: #1^^J}\oldhypertarget{#1}}%
%  \let\oldrefstepcounter\refstepcounter
%  \def\refstepcounter{\message{^^J!!!Href: \detokenize\expandafter{\@currentHref}^^J}\oldrefstepcounter}%
%}%
%\makeatother

%MyStripToColon (requires xstring)
\newcommand{\mystriptocolon}[2]{\StrCut{#1}{.}{\myonea}{\myoneb}%
  \StrCut{#2}{.}{\mytwoa}{\mytwob}%
  \IfStrEq{\myonea}{\mytwoa}{\mytwob}{#2}%
}

% Cleveref Label Formatting

\crefname{ExNo}{}{}
\crefname{SubExNo}{}{}
\crefname{SubSubExNo}{}{}

\creflabelformat{ExNo}{#2#1#3}          % The output of the \cref command doesn't include parentheses.
\creflabelformat{SubExNo}{#2#1#3}
\creflabelformat{SubSubExNo}{#2#1#3}        

\crefrangelabelformat{ExNo}{#3#1#4--#5#2#6}                 
\crefrangelabelformat{SubExNo}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}        
\crefrangelabelformat{SubSubExNo}{%
  \SelectAccordingToStyleFlag{#3#1#4--#5\mystriptocolon{#1}{#2}#6}{% <- default-format
    {#3#1#4--#5\mystriptocolon{#1}{#2}#6}% <- Format if value of \StyleFlag is 1
    {#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}% <- Format if value of \StyleFlag is 2
    % Append more if \StyleFlag can also be 3 or 4 or etc
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{–} 

\begin{document}

% Philex Label Formatting

\phildashes{}{.}        
\subformat{a}{}{.}
\subsubformat{i}{(}{)}

\lb{main1}{This is main1.
    \lba{sub1}{This is sub1.
        \lba{subsub11}{This is subsub11.}
        \lbz{subsub12}{This is subsub12.}}
    \lbz{sub2}{This is sub2.
        \lba{subsub21}{This is subsub21.}
        \lbz{subsub22}{This is subsub22.}}}
\lb{main2}{This is main2.}
                

\verb|\mystriptocolon| works like a charm:

\vspace{6pt}

\SetStyleFlag{1}%
\verb|\crefrange{sub1}{sub2}| \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{sub1}{sub2}

\vspace{6pt}

\verb|\crefrange{subsub11}{subsub12}| \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{subsub11}{subsub12}

\vspace{6pt}

\textbf{The philex-formatting is changed:}
    
\phildashes{.}{}    
\subformat{1}{}{.}  
\subsubformat{a}{}{.}   
    
\lb{main3}{This is main3.
    \lba{sub31}{This is sub31.
        \lba{subsub311}{This is subsub311.}
        \lbz{subsub312}{This is subsub312.}}
    \lbz{sub32}{This is sub32.}}
    
\vspace{6pt}
            
\textbf{The Style-flag is changed from 1 to 2 to have other branch of 
        \texttt{\string\crefrangelabelformat\string{SubSubExNo\string}} in effect:}

\vspace{6pt}
        
\verb|\SetStyleFlag{2}|\SetStyleFlag{2}%

\verb|\crefrange{subsub311}{subsub312}| \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{subsub311}{subsub312}

\vspace{6pt}

As you can see, you obtain 3.1a--b without the 1 being repeated.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time, I will study your post carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I will take the problem the other way around:

- Use \crefstripprefix by default, i.e. abandon `xstring`'s `\StrCut` approach;
- use `refcount`'s `\getrefbykeydefault` when necessary

  (credit Ulrich Diez https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577464/262813)

```
     \documentclass{article}
        
        \usepackage{indentfirst}
        \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
        \usepackage{cleveref}
        \usepackage{philex}
        
        \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
       
        % Cleveref Label Formatting
        
                    \crefname{ExNo}{}{}
                    \crefname{SubExNo}{}{}
                    \crefname{SubSubExNo}{}{}
                
                    \creflabelformat{ExNo}{#2#1#3}      
                    \creflabelformat{SubExNo}{#2#1#3}
                    \creflabelformat{SubSubExNo}{#2#1#3}        
                    
                    \crefrangelabelformat{ExNo}{#3#1#4--#5#2#6}                 
                    \crefrangelabelformat{SubExNo}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}        
                    \crefrangelabelformat{SubSubExNo}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
                    
                    \newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{–}
                    
                    
                    
       % Skips everything before the dot.
                        
                \makeatletter
            \@ifdefinable\gobbletodot{\long\def\gobbletodot#1.{}}% refcount package
            \newcommand\delbefdot[1]{%
                    \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\gobbletodot#1.}$%
                    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
                          {#1}{\expandafter\delbefdot\expandafter{\gobbletodot#1}}%
                        }%
            \@ifdefinable\rfxx{%
                    \DeclareRobustCommand\rfxx[1]{%
                      \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{\refused{#1}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%
                                                {%
                                                  \@ifundefined{hyperref}{\@firstofone}{\hyperref[{#1}]}%
                                                  {%
                                                    (\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\delbefdot
                                                    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{??}})%
                                                  }%
                                                }%
                          }%
                        }%
                        
            \@ifdefinable\rnxx{%
                    \DeclareRobustCommand\rnxx[1]{%
                      \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{\refused{#1}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%
                                                {%
    \@ifundefined{hyperref}{\@firstofone}{\hyperref[{#1}]}%
                                                  {%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\delbefdot
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{??}}%
                                                  }%
                                                }%
                          }%
                        }%
                \makeatother
                            
                            
                            
                            
       \newcommand{\rfstrip}[2]{(\rn{#1}--\rnx{#2})} % (3.1--2)
       \newcommand{\rnstrip}[2]{\rn{#1}--\rnx{#2}} % 3.1--2
       \newcommand{\rfdoublestrip}[2]{(\rn{#1}--\rnxx{#2})} %  (3.1a--b)
       \newcommand{\rndoublestrip}[2]{\rn{#1}--\rnxx{#2}} % 3.1a--b
    
\begin{document}
    
        % Philex Label Formatting
        
                \phildashes{}{.}        
                \subformat{a}{}{.}
                \subsubformat{i}{(}{)}
    
            \lb{main1}{This is main1.
                \lba{sub11}{This is sub11.
                    \lba{subsub111}{This is subsub111.}
                    \lbz{subsub112}{This is subsub112.}}
                \lbz{sub12}{This is sub12.
                    \lba{subsub121}{This is subsub121.}
                    \lbz{subsub122}{This is subsub122.}}}
                    
            \lb{main2}{This is main2.}
         
\textbackslash crefrange\{sub11\}\{sub12\} \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{sub11}{sub12}  This works (no roman numbering).

\textbackslash crefrange\{subsub111\}\{subsub112\} \textrightarrow{}  This will NOT compile fine (roman).
    
\textbackslash rnstrip\{sub11\}\{sub12\} \textrightarrow{} \rnstrip{sub11}{sub12} This works, because \textbackslash rnx doesn't work on the base of stripping to a delimiter.

\textbackslash rndoublestrip\{subsub111\}\{subsub112\} \textrightarrow{} \rndoublestrip{subsub111}{subsub112} Works, thanks to the dot.

    \vspace{3ex}
    \textbf{Now I change label formatting.}
        
                \phildashes{.}{}    
                \subformat{1}{}{.}  
                \subsubformat{a}{}{.}   
        
    \lb{main3}{This is main3.
        \lba{sub31}{This is sub31.
            \lba{subsub311}{This is subsub311.}
            \lbz{subsub312}{This is subsub312.}}
        \lbz{sub32}{This is sub32.}}

\textbackslash rnstrip\{sub31\}\{sub32\} \textrightarrow{} \rnstrip{sub31}{sub32} This works fine, thanks to the dot.

\textbackslash rndoublestrip\{subsub311\}\{subsub312\} \textrightarrow{} \rndoublestrip{subsub311}{subsub312} Cannot work (no delim.)

\textbackslash crefrange\{sub31\}\{sub32\} \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{sub31}{sub32} This works fine (no roman).

\textbackslash crefrange\{subsub311\}\{subsub312\} \textrightarrow{} \crefrange{subsub311}{subsub312} This works fine (no roman).


\end{document}
```

[image]