# Four levels of examples

Tags: linguex

`Linguex` only allows for 3 levels of examples, but I need to be able to reproduce this (except I do not need first level label to include chapter number or be flushed right).

- I want to keep local referencing to subexamples, i.e. parent sublabel skipping.
- If we want to skip the first and second levels as in (1b) instead of (28.E.1b), and if a dot is involved as a separator, the `refcount` package can be called, so as to use the \gobbletodot and \getrefkeybykeydefault macros

  - cf. [Any way to reference a particular component of a label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577449/any-way-to-reference-a-particular-component-of-a-label/577464#577464) (thanks to Ulrich Diez).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be ideal, but the [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) package can certainly handle something like that.

EDIT: I've edited the answer to also include a counter for the example number that goes on the right; it's a bit hacky, and there may be more elegant solutions, especially if it were OK for those to be on the left as well. Maybe someone will have a better idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{myexample}
\setcounter{myexample}{0}

\newenvironment{myexamples}{%
    \hbox{\smash{\raisebox{-1\baselineskip}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\hfill% 
        \refstepcounter{myexample}(\themyexample)}}}}\nointerlineskip%
    \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}\begin{enumerate}%
}{%
    \end{enumerate}
}

\setlist{noitemsep}
\setlist[1]{label=\Alph*.,leftmargin=4em}
\setlist[2]{label=\arabic*.,leftmargin=1.5em,labelsep=0.3em,
    ref=\arabic{myexample}.\Alph{enumi}.\arabic*}
\setlist[3]{label=\alph*.,leftmargin=*,
    ref=\arabic{myexample}.\Alph{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}\alph*}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexamples}
    \item \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{enumerate}
                \item John is a robber.\label{johnrobber}
                \item John is a thief.
              \end{enumerate}
        \item \begin{enumerate}
                \item John robs things.
                \item *John thieves things. (compare \emph{thievery}) \label{johnthievery}
              \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{myexamples}

As you can see in \ref{johnrobber} and \ref{johnthievery} \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image: updated list output]

(If you need to share the numbers with another example set, say, for linguex as is, more might need to be done.)

Comment: The idea is that you have to be able to refer to the example including the first level, as "cf. 2.E.b2".

Comment: I'm a little confused by "2.E.b2", since that doesn't match the example, but with "A.1" and "1.a", I was just going by the example in the top of the first paragraph of the second page; you can make the reference tags read however you want, so, e.g., `ref=\Alph{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}\alph*` in `\setlist[3]` for "A.2b". See the package documentation.

Comment: This is example (28) so basically you want to refer to eg (28.D.2b) The notation F.1 skips the first level, which is what you do when talking about one example.

Comment: Oh, I see. Bit busy right now, but I'll try to make something like that work when I get a chance.

Comment: I've made an edit to the answer that incorporates the example numbers, but it's a bit cobbled together; someone else may have something more elegant.

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted, he probably has no idea how much explanation I put in my other post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637164/cross-referencing-more-sublevels-and-presets

Comment: Thank you very much! So now if, discussing the example more thoroughly, I want to skip the main level label, such as "A.1a" or even the sublevel "1a", is that possible?

Comment: @VincentKrebs As far as I know, for that, you'd either need to do `\hyperlink`/`\hypertarget`s with manual numbering, or else simplify the `ref=` options to use just `\Alph*`, `\arabic`, etc., and then chain together the `\ref`s to the separately labeled components you want to include each time, which would be a little annoying I admit. (The downvote is pretty mysterious to me too!)

Comment: I do not know how to refer to a specific part, although I know this post very well now https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577449/any-way-to-reference-a-particular-component-of-a-label/577464#577464
If I can know how to ref to the middle level label for example, I can create a command such as "\reftwolv[2]= \ref #1.\ref #2"

Comment: I got it, I use \newcommand{\reftwolv}{\arabic{enumii}\alph{enumiii}}, something like that. But I don"t understand how to include the label as an argument of the command.

Comment: I'm not sure, but think you're after something like `\newcommand{\reftwolv}[2]{\ref{#1}.\ref{#2}}` which would then be used like `\reftwolv{outerlabel}{innerlabel}`. The `\arabic{enumii}` stuff should be left to the `ref=` stuff that is put in the `\setlist` commands, but most likely you don't need to use enumi/enumii/enumiii at all, but just the simpler `\Alph*`, `\arabic*`, `\alph*` shorthands at the end of my examples: `\setlist[2]{..., ref=\arabic*}`, etc. (Or just leave the `ref=` options out so it defaults to the `label=` options.)

Comment: What I never understood is how you define sublabels, i.e. labels for a precise sublevel, in your example if ref=\arabic*, this is the "innerlabel" but how do you call the "outerlabel"?

Comment: In the code you'd need to have separate `\label` commands for each the levels right after the `\item` command for that level, e.g., `\item\label{outerlabel} \begin{enumerate}\item\label{innerlabel} \begin{enumerate}\item\label{innerinnerlabel} John is a robber.`

Comment: Ok, yes it will not be that convenient. I wish I could find a way to type things such as \newcommand{\reftwolv}{\label{#1}.\sublabel{#1}}, i.e. refer to sublabels of one example. Thanks for your help anyway!